# Port an sql database file to another machine

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

How can I port a .mdf SQL server database file to another machine .. I have a database file that I have tested and its working. It uses windows authentication. When I test the connection in the other machine it says Connection Successful but the data could not be inserted. The application is the same in both machine. Any suggestion on how can I host my database remotely. Thanks

Comment: How did you "test the connection"? An MDF file can only be attached to a single SQL Server at a time. So please show your connection string and how you've verified that each application is actually connecting to its own copy of the database.

Comment: Actually I copied the Asp.net application project file which have an .mdf database file in its AppData folder . Its working in one machine but not in the other machine.

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server Management Studio, have you gone to Security -> User Logins and selected the user you are using to connect with and check the user mapping?  Right click on the user and then select properties, then user mapping.

Comment: Sorry but I don't have SQL Server Management Studio , I have SQL Server Express Edition.Let me download SQL Server Management Studio. Thanks